# Page with URL variable is not being redirected correctly. Angular2 routing

Tags: angular, authorization, angular2-routing

I am doing an angular4 application with ASP.NET Web API 2. I have to get the current user and then check the if he is allowed to access the admin portal.

my routing file is:

```
{ path: ':lang', component: LanguageComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard],
      children: [
        { path: 'admin/:comp', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
        { path: 'admin/news', component: NewsComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
        { path: 'admin/news/edit/:id', component: NewsEditComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
      ]
}
```

LoginGuard will connect to the server and will send a value of true if the user is logged in and will save the profile in a global variable. (it will be called overall).

AdministratorGuard will check the global variable and if he is an admin and allowed to access the page.

Everything works fine. The problem is with F5 or with writing the URL directly.

If I go to the default page and then navigate to the admin page, it will work correctly.

If I go through this URL directly, it will work:

> localhost/en-us/admin/news

but this URL:

> localhost/en-us/admin/news/edit/1

will be redirected to the URL

> localhost/en-us/admin

I don't know why? It is giving me no error, but with an unusual redirect to the default admin page. And this is happening with all the URLs that contain id in the URL. They will be redirected to the default portal they fit in.

any Ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
{
    path: ':lang',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: LanguageComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
        { path: 'admin/news', component: NewsComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard] },
        { path: 'admin/news/edit/:id', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard] },
        { path: 'admin/:comp', component: NewsEditComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard] },
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Samy i will updated my answer. hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the routes

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'localhost/en-us/admin/news', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: ':lang', component: LanguageComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard],
      children: [
    { path: 'admin/news', component: NewsComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
    { path: 'admin/news/edit/:id', component: NewsEditComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
    { path: 'admin/:comp', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdministratorGuard]},
      ]
}
```

otherwise the `AdminComponent` route matches always first and the others aren't even checked.

Comment: Are you using PathLocationStrategy (default) and does your server support it or are you using HashLocationStrategy? Have you tried with HashLocationStrategy (`imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`)?

Comment: It goes into endless loop. when I added this userHash: true

Comment: With what URL? Already on initial load of `index.html`? The URL looks differently when `useHash` is used.

Comment: Yes, it is always redirecting itself to the index.html and then to the endless loop.

Comment: I added a route at the beginning. Can you try that please.

Comment: I have tried it, and it still not working. I received and parsing Error. I think I have to recreate the routing file and reordering it. Do you have any source where I can find the standard official routing?

Comment: I think the first route requires `pathMatch: 'full'` (see updated answer)

Comment: yes, it was missing, there is no error right now, but the same problem still exists. Still redirecting itself when the id is in the URL.